# Find element by Xpath with multiple variables in different descendants

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to find an element based on variable content of descendants. I was looking at several posts here on stackoverflow, but, unfortunately, couldn't figure out how to adapt them to my situation. In fact, I'm trying to find the following list element `<li>`, which contains the string variable `facility` (no matter where) and a descendant div with the string variable `lesson_time`:

```
<div class="day">
  <li class="btn-hover-parent"> ... </li>
  <li class="btn-hover-parent"> ... </li>
  <li class="btn-hover-parent"> ... </li>
  <li class="btn-hover-parent"> ... </li>
  <li class="btn-hover-parent"> 
    <a class="xy" href="...">
      <div class="abc">
        <div class="text-h4">This is the text</div>
        ...
      </div>
      ...
    </a>
  </li>
</div>
```

Since each `<li>` can contain one of the variables, I need to use the AND operator to find the element which matches both variables. I managed to search the `<li>`'s like this:

```
day_ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='day'][contains(., '" + args.day + "')]")
day_ele.find_element_by_xpath(".//li[@class='btn-hover-parent'][contains(., '" + args.facility + "')][contains(., '" + args.lesson_time + "')]").click()
```

However, this searches for the variables in any place of `<li>`, which is a problem in my case. For `lesson_time`, I explicitly want to search in `<div class="text-h4">`. I tried something like this:

```
day_ele.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='btn-hover-parent'][contains(., '" + args.facility + "')] and ./div[@class='text-h4'][contains(., '" + args.lesson_time + "')]").click()
```

However, this tells me the XPath expression is invalid. Each search term for itself works. I think I'm doing something wrong with `./div`. I also tried `.//div` and `div`, but none of them worked.

Doing it with Python 3 Selenium, if this matters.

Answer (score 0):

U can use `BeautifulSoup` like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="day">
  <li class="btn-hover-parent"> ... </li>
  <li class="btn-hover-parent"> ... </li>
  <li class="btn-hover-parent"> ... </li>
  <li class="btn-hover-parent"> ... </li>
  <li class="btn-hover-parent"> 
    <a class="xy" href="...">
      <div class="abc">
        <div class="text-h4">This is the text</div>
        ...
      </div>
      ...
    </a>
  </li>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

li_items = soup.find_all('li',class_ = "btn-hover-parent")

for li in li_items:
    try:
        print(li.a.div.div.text)
    except:
        pass
```

Output:

```
This is the text
```

This works. But if u have the div tag between multiple div tags that hold other values, then change the `for loop` to this:

```
for li in li_items:
    try:
        a = li.find('a',class_ = "xy")
        div1 = a.find('div',class_ = "abc")
        div2 = div1.find('div',class_ = "text-h4")
        print(div2.text)
    except:
        pass
```

Output:

```
This is the text
```

Hope that this helps!

Comment: I don't think this hierarchical query will work in my case. The problem I'm having is not finding the text if all `div`s are unique. It's to find the `<li>` with a text string from a variable in div1 in combination with a text string from a variable in div2.

Comment: An example would help me to better understand ur requirement

Comment: Your post gave me another idea. I can do find_elements_by_xpath() to get a list of all elements containing my first variable, and then iterate through this list to search for the second variable. This makes the syntax a little bit easier.

Comment: Yeah...That's a good idea. I think that I understood ur requirement. U have two vars, containing 2 values. U want to print all the strings that contain those two vars. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Each `<li>` has `<div1>` and `<div2>` (same level) and I need to search for the `<li>` with the desired combination of div1 and div2 based on a text string in these divs. The two text strings I'm searching for are not static, but come from variables. Would be very elegant if I can do this in a one-liner with an `AND` operator like in my initial post.

Comment: On what basis do u wanna compare the strings?

Comment: U can maybe post the url of the website that u r tryna scrape so that it would be easier for me to understand ur requirement